# white space under footer in chrome

Tags: c#

i am developing one site for job portal in asp.net with C#.
in this i am using jquery.dd.js file for dropdown styles.
my problem is that white space is displaying beneath the footer.
wherever i use the dropdown,the extra white space is displaying beneath footer.
if i use the HTML select, white space will gone.
but if i use asp.net dropdown control, then white space is appear.

in IE and firefox browser, it is working fine.

any one help me to resolve this issue?

Regards,
Lalitha

Comment: post some code.. fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

might this css property will help , Use at appropriate position

```
.yourClassName{
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0px;
   line-height: .7em;
 }
```

Comment: hi,i have fixed this issue.. i am using jquery plugin for dropdown. it makes the footer overflow. so i added the dropdown inside a div. now it is working fine.